# Storing users 'following' during a PHP session

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple followers/following system set up within my app.

What would be the best way to store a complete array of 'users following' during a session so that I don't have to query the database multiple times throughout.

To clarify:  When a user logs in once they have been authorized I query the database, get a full list of users that the logged in user is following and ultimately store it as a JavaScript variable.  This way throughout the site, as the user navigates around I can constantly check the following status against any other user they may come across.

This query is only performed once when the user loads the full page, while navigating around it is not repeated.

This works well for javascript generated content i.e user hovercards etc...

However I would like to store this array (of only userid's) in PHP itself so that I can prevent further queries to the following table while generating content server side that requires a 'follower/following' check to be performed.

What would be the best way to do this?

Please bare in mind that the results are cached in memcached but if I can avoid any lookups at all and have a consistent array to check against that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me get this right, you want to store this list so it isn't queried on each page?

First I would recommend you only perform this query on pages that need this data and second I would say that on these pages you don't try this.

Imagine a user stops following or starts following. Some complex cache calculator or event bubbler programmed into your own PHP app to purge the foreign session of data (which is bad, the user has access to data that is not their own, a session infact) could be tiedious with security and performance.

The better thing to do is to perform the query again for each new page. This would be much easier, probably more performant and wouldn't be micro-optimising.

### Edit

If you are picking out 10k rows on one page then you might be doing something wrong. You might be looking at it from the wrong perspective.

Comment: You are correct that is exactly what I want to do. Every page unfortunately, will require this query to be run since every page shows some detail about other users... The logic is already in place to update the array that is stored in memcached without completely destroying the cache therefore applying it to an array stored in the app itself would be trivial. Regardless thanks, I'm looking for opinions either way on this, as like you said, it may be completely unneeded.

Comment: @gordyr Having made a lot of scalable apps myself and even worked on a couple of high profile apps I have never seen memcached used in this way efficiently. Normally it is used to house SQL result sets (or other data that is rare modified) instead of querying directly but it seems like you wanna take it a step further and have memcache somehow trace changes without pinging SQL...it sounds undoable.

Comment: Thanks this is useful info.  What I am trying to do is prepare this app to be as scale-able as possible.  My thought process is as follows: In this app user's do not frequently add/remove followers, most of their time will be spent using the app itself.  Therefore storing these results in memcached appears to make sense as they are small arrays of userid's. Would performing a query on a table with for e.g 10 million rows extracting that users list of followers several times during a users session be acceptable?  Please forgive my ignorance I have never had to deal with such large dataset

Comment: @gordyr Yea as henrik mentions with an index this would be massively fast and wtih sharding ontop you mght only be looking at like 200k record on any computer at any given point in time. You can then use memcached ontop like fb does to lessen the weight of simultaneous and quick succession calls

Comment: Great, thanks... I guess i'll go back to the drawing board and keep this simple then.

Comment: @gordyr Yea though, in theory you are not totally worng. Being a privacy person myself I like to delete stuff from my twitter and fb so I notice the flaws in their caching very quickly. I have noticed that fb has very few flaws while twitter waits anything upto 3 minutes to refresh most lists, this is the extreme use case of memcached and personally I would use memcached for cache stuff that naturally needs caching like hjuge aggregation queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in the session variable.

- http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm
- https://www.google.se/search?q=learning+sessions+php

**UPDATE**

Store the current user in a session and add it to the queries you are already doing to fetch the popup information and add that it tests if the popups person follows the current user.

Comment: This was my initial thought.... However I was concerned about the array becoming too large at for instance 10,000 followers or so. Would you consider storing the followers data in a session standard practice? Thanks.

Comment: 10,000 is a bit much data and changes the ballgame. If that is the case your query to the database when the user visits one of his followers page, or creates a hover, would be a better place and not store the whole list at all. With good indexes it should be lightningfast compared to going through 10,000 posts in a PHP array.

Comment: Thanks Henrik - This would be simple however every single page in the app contains information about users that you are following or are following you.  Of course I can simply check if the row exists for every user every time it is needed but this seems innefficient to me.

Comment: I'm glad you are going to rethink the process, it just didn't feel right of the bat.

Answer (score 1):

The two ways that come to mind would be to just write joins with well placed indexes each time, which you've said you don't want to do, and just a simple array in the session, which would probably look something like this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['following']) {
    $following = $user->getFollowingIds(); //some query in here to get an array of ids
    $_SESSION['following'] = $following;
    $_SESSION['following_str'] = implode(',', $following);
}
```

Then whenever you want to pull all of the statuses for the people that `$user` is following you can write a query, something like this:

```
$query('SELECT status.* FROM status WHERE user_id IN (' . $_SESSION['following_str'] . ')'); //not sanitized or safe but you get the idea
```